# Assetic doesn't copy image from css to web path

Tags: css, symfony

i have following block in my header.html.twig

```html
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' '../src/SkaLab/Bundle/FrontEndBundle/Resources/public/css/styles.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

and in my css stylesheet i have following lines:

```css
.container.login {
    background:url('imgs/hand-tools-1.jpg');
}
```

and in config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ SkaLabFrontEndBundle ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

when i launch assetic with following command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

it generates all in web directory, but i don't understand why image in background url no.
Anyone can help me, please?
How can i figure out to have background url image (from css code) in web path like others resources (like css and js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the command :

```
php app/console assets:install
```

This will generate the bundles folder in your web path and your images in it.

If you put a relative path in your css, this will be interpreted as : 
`yoursite.com/bundles/yourbundle/css`

So if you put `imgs/hand-tools-1.jpg` symfony will look for an `imgs` folder in the path below.

The best way is to use absolute path. the `/` of the absolute path is your web directory (the only one which is public). so you can change your image path by :

```
.container.login {
    background:url('/./yourPathToImgsFolderInWeb/imgs/hand-tools-1.jpg');
}
```

For example : If you have a structure like this :

```
web
   css
   bundles
       appbundle
           imgs
               hand-tools-1.jpg
```

So you've to replace `yourPathToImgsFolderInWeb` by `bundles/appbundle`

Comment: thank you Julien for your feedback. in my web directory i have css, js, bundles directories; i don't understand why if i try access to something in css (like css/xxx.css) or something in js like (js/xxx.js) it's work, while if i try access to something in bundles directory (always inside web) it doesn't work. Can you give me some suggestion about this problem, please?

Comment: I update my answer. I tried to explain a little bit more the process.

Comment: thank you so much Julien. also with your help i figure out. my real problem was in .htaccess.

Comment: Oh ok ! Sorry Sergio, but thanks for the feedback. Have fun with your project.